# Куда поступают заказы из прайс листа instant cms

Tags: веб-программирование, cms

Использую на своём сайте Instant CMS 1.10. Включил компонент "Прайс-лист". На сайте оформил заказ. Появилось сообщение:

```
Спасибо!Ваш заказ поступил в обработку.Наши менеджеры свяжутся с вами по указанному телефону в ближайшее время.
```

Как мне теперь обработать заказ? Где найти нужную информацию?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В админке: компоненты/прайс-лист/ смотрим "E-mail продавца :"Заказы отправляются по адресу указанному там. Судя по всему происходит блокировка на уровне почтового сервера. Yandex получает письма, а Google их блокирует, даже в спам не помещает. Но если эти письма идут сначала на Yandex, а потом скачиваются Google то они помечаются как "СПАМ"